# Is there a way to comment more than one entry at a time in cron?

Tags: linux, cron, aix

I know the standard way to disable a task in `cron` is to comment the line with the task using the `#` sign in front of it, as with most Unix config files or shell scripts.  e.g.:

```
53 23 * * * /home/dolan/y-u-du-dis.sh 2>&1
```

That's fine for just one task, but it's really annoying having to comment 100 lines or so...  so the question is:  **Is there a way to comment more than one entry at a time in cron?**  Something like multi-line comments, or a shortcut to comment everything in the crontab...

I found [**this question and answer in ServerFault**](https://serverfault.com/questions/183399/can-you-have-a-multi-line-comment-a-crontab), which basically says that you can't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer from SF is accurate as far as it goes, though if all the lines you wish to comment are in one block there is a way "around" this problem. It's not standard practice, and the end result is individual comment markers on every line. My editor of choice for crontab files is `vi`, so other editors may or may not have similar functionality, but if you wish to comments lines 5 through 80, you could issue the following command sequence in `vi`:

```
 :5,80s/^/# /
```

Which has the effect of putting a '# ' at the beginning of lines 5 through 80. Hackish? Absolutely. Effective? Under the constraints I've given, yes.

Comment: Right now, I'm using `AIX` with `vi` as the default text editor, so this works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: Love this answer - major time saver, thank you! If anyone is wondering, to edit the crontab with vi try this:  export VISUAL=vim; crontab -e